# Is there a way to display the fourth heading level in the Navigation Pane in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

I am missing the fourth (and fifth) heading level in the Navigation Pane in Word.

How do I activate those?

[image: Check Outline level]

I have Word 2013.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set a style to be 'Heading' in Word 2013?](http://superuser.com/questions/516674/how-do-i-set-a-style-to-be-heading-in-word-2013)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the proposed question.  The proposed duplicate addresses *how to make a custom style appear in the Navigation Pane* while this question seeks to expose the *built-in* Heading styles 4 and greater.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Word 2013 does not display styles `Heading 4` and greater until you use the highest numbered heading level *currently* displayed.

To add **Heading 4** to the available styles, apply **Heading 3** style somewhere in your document.  `Heading 4` will immediately become visible in the *Styles* group on the ribbon.

Use **Heading 4** and `Heading 5` will become available, and so on.

Comment: If it does not when using own styles, make sure that for your Heading 4 the correct Outline level (Level 4) is set. To check this right-click the Heading 4 in the Styles (Ctrl-Alt-Shift-S), Modify..., Format, Paragraph, Outline level shall be Level 4.

Comment: Not working with Word 2003 ... ?any other way...

Comment: @ZEE you should ask a new [question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). This one is for office 2013.

Comment: Thanks Twisty... but there is a great chance that the procedure is the same for a great part of the MS Office range... (as it is in other office features)

Comment: That's true, but Word 2003 is very different from modern versions of Office... Particularly versions after 2007.